# How to change hidden filed attribute by mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

There is a hidden input field that have an attribute named `disabled`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Foo" value="Foo" disabled="disabled">
```

I can get the field like this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
f = agent.get(url).form_with(name: 'form_name')
f.field_with(name: 'Foo')
```

And I want to set `disabled = false` before submit the form.
But I couldn't figure out how to set attibute except for `value` attribute.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you remove the attribute? To enable the input you just need to remove the disabled attribute completely. Or is there another reason for setting it to false?

Comment: That's not going to do anything, only the name and value get sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
field.node.remove_attribute 'disabled'
```